# Angular 6 show spinner between route changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Currently, i created a spinner component

```
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationCancel, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-spinner',
    templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnDestroy {

    public isSpinnerVisible = true;
    constructor(private router: Router) {

        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                this.isSpinnerVisible = true;

            } else if ( event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError) {
                this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
            }
        }, () => {
            this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
    }

}
```

inside app.component.html

```
<router-outlet>
    <app-spinner></app-spinner>
</router-outlet>
```

spinner.component.html

```
<div class="preloader" *ngIf="isSpinnerVisible">
    <div class="spinner">
    <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
    <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

however, it is not showing, and NavigationEnd quickly triggers even if some background ajax are not yet completed

Comment: try https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 1):

```
public isSpinnerVisible = true;
constructor(private router: Router) {

    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.isSpinnerVisible = true;

        } else if ( event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError) {
            this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
        }
    }, () => {
        this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
    });
}


<router-outlet>
    <app-spinner *ngIf="isSpinnerVisible=='ture'"></app-spinner>
</router-outlet>
```

Comment: but best way to used spanner is used in a component not in app compoent

Comment: i forgot to add the html of the component.

Comment: < app-spinner>< /app-spinner> must be OUT < router-outlet> < /router-outlet>